# Address Validation Python

Tags: python, oracle, python-2.7

I'm having issues with the data repeating itself instead of looping in the following script. How can I get the script to provide the correct address from the api for each row?

[My code]: *Please excuse the crappy code layout too. I'm a noob!*

```
'''
This is a tool to pull address data from a db, validate the extracted 
addresses, and save the updated addresses to Excel for the DBAs to update
'''
#Modules used
import cx_Oracle #Connect to the Oracle db and pull the data
import lob #The api that does the address validation (https://lob.com)
import pandas as pd

#Lob API key received by signing up at the Lob website
lob.api_key = '<key>'

#SQL script to display the open orders and their addresses
sqlscript = '''
        select order_number,
               address1,
               address2,
               city,
               state,
               postcode,
               country
        from orders_table
        '''
#Connect to the database 
con = cx_Oracle.connect('un/pw@db')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(sqlscript)

# Create dataframe from SQL
columns = [desc[0] for desc in cur.description]

#I'm using cur.fetchmany(2) for testing so I'm not hitting the db for 40k 
#rows everytime; once this script is validated, will 
#change to fetchall()

data = cur.fetchmany(2)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(data), columns=columns)

'''
The rest of this script is a struggle for me. 
'''
for order_number,address1,address2,city,state,postcode,country in dataOld:
  verifiedAddress = lob.Verification.create(
      address_line1 = address1,
      address_line2 = address2,
      address_city = city,
      address_state = state,
      address_zip = postcode,
      address_country = country
    )

row1 = verifiedAddress.address.address_line1
row2 = verifiedAddress.address.address_line2
row3 = verifiedAddress.address.address_city
row4 = verifiedAddress.address.address_state
row5 = verifiedAddress.address.address_zip

idx2 = 2
df1.insert(idx2, "updated_address1", row1)
idx4 = 4
df1.insert(idx4, "updated_address2", row2)
idx6 = 6
df1.insert(idx6, "updated_city", row3)
idx8 = 8
df1.insert(idx8, "updated_state", row4)
idx10 = 10
df1.insert(idx10, "updated_zip", row5)

#print df1

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('garbage.xlsx')
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='extract')
writer.save()

print 'File creation complete'
cur.close()
con.close()
```

Below is what I'm currently getting. How can I get the script to provide the correct address from the api for each row?

[image: Results from above script]

Comment: Please concentrate on the problem within your question. We care about the fact that you want to validate addresses but not about how bad addresses impact your business processes. That's not in the domain of programming anymore.

Comment: Understood, Klaus D. I just wanted to make sure all of you experts understood the business needs and every aspect of the issue, but I will try my hardest to leave out the unnecessary fluff. I will edit the post and put the main question up top.

Comment: So what is your actual question?

Comment: Break down the problem, and you also might want to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help